# Generate permutation using bitmask

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am generating all permutations of a string using bitmask.

```
void recurse(string s, int mask,int taken){

    if(taken == n){
        cout << " ";
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(((1 << i) & mask) == 0){
            cout << s[i];
            recurse(s, (mask|(1 << i)), taken + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

In this function n is the length of the string. I am keeping track of how many characters are printed so far using taken variable. 
In the main function I am calling

```
recurse(s,0,0);
```

But this is not working correctly.
For input

> red

Its output is

> red
>   de
>   erd
>   dr
>   dre
>   er

Where I am going wrong?

---

**UPDATE**
// Below code works fine.

```
void recurse(string s, int mask,int taken, string pref){

    if(taken == n){
        cout << pref <<endl; 
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(((mask >> i) & 1) == 0){
            recurse(s,(mask | (1 << i)),taken + 1, pref + s[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As-is this will not compile. What is `n`?

Comment: I can't. I have to break the recursion once some condition gets false, as an optimization. next_permutation will take lot of time for large string.

Comment: n is global variable.

Comment: You output the beginning of the string just once before calling your routine multiply for the tail. Therefor, the beginning is omitted for every 2nd call.

Comment: ohh. so I think I will have to keep a string buffer for every recursion path and print the prefix from that buffer ?

Comment: @Mustafa You could (should) send your working update as answer. (You even may [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the questioner provided the answer himself. (Congratulation.)

As I already started to fiddle (couldn't resist) I want to present my solution as well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void recurse(
  const string &s, unsigned mask = 0, const string &out = string())
{
  size_t n = s.size();
  if (out.size() == n) cout << ' ' << out;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    unsigned bit = 1 << i;
    if (mask & bit) continue;
    recurse(s, mask | bit, out + s[i]);
  }
}

int main()
{
  string test = "red";
  recurse(test);
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested:

```
 red rde erd edr dre der
```

`recurse()` iterates through all characters of `s` looking for one which is not already marked in the `mask` as taken. Each found characters is added to output `out`. Then, the recursive call repeats it for all untaken characters.

Check out the sample code yourself on [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/6YVBh7).

Answer (score 0):

[Permutation tree for 'abc'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8wvD.png)

Your first code was visiting each node of this tree **once** and printing a character. So it was giving wrong output.

On a different note, you have used some redundant variables.

Instead of `n` you should use `s.size()`.

In the second code instead of `taken` you you should use `pref.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version. It's different from the questioner's code in 2 ways:

1. The parameter `taken` can be omitted and we can use `mask + 1 == (1 << n)` instead. It basically checks if bits `1` to `n-1` of `mask` are all 1's. If so, then the recursion depth is `n` and we print the permutation.
2. Copying the `string pref` in each iteration can be slow if the size of the string is large. We can instead use a reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void recurse(string s, int mask, string &pref);

int n = 3;

int main()
{
    string pref("");
    recurse(string("abc"), 0, pref);
    return 0;
}

void recurse(string s, int mask, string &pref)
{
    if (mask + 1 == (1 << n)) {
        cout << pref << endl;
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (((mask >> i) & 1) == 0) {
            pref += s[i];
            recurse(s, (mask | (1 << i)), pref);
            pref.erase(pref.end() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

where `n` is the size of the string. The output is

```
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```